# How do I get the joystick axis as a float in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make audio play at the same speed as the player movement. Right now I have the audio playing as a float and the character moving with Unity's character controller. How do I get the controller x and y axis as a float?

```
//Moving/Jumping
public CharacterController controller;

public float originalSpeed = 12;
public float speed = 12;
public float sprintSpeed = 20;
public float crouchSpeed = 5;
public float gravity = -50;
public float jumpHeight = 3f;

Vector3 velocity;

public float defaultSprintTime;
public float sprintTime;

private float x;
private float y;
```

In the update function:

```
        //Getting the movement input
    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    //Moving the player
    Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

    controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

In the audio coroutine:

```
if (playingStoneSound == false)
    {
        int randomSound = Random.Range(0, FootstepStone.Length); //Makes an int which randomly generates what audio source in the array should be played
        FootstepStone[randomSound].Play(); //Plays audio from the array using the randomly generated int
        playingStoneSound = true; //Making the bool true so you cannot play the sound again until it is done

        if (stillCrouching == true) //If you are crouching play the sound slower
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.85f); //Waits before playing the sound again
            playingStoneSound = false; //Making the bool false so you can play the sound again
        }
        else //If you are not crouching
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(speed); //Waits before playing the sound again -- This is where I want my audio to change depending on the joystick speed
            playingStoneSound = false; //Making the bool false so you can play the sound again
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I don't get something, but as you have your speed values already read in update, what's stopping you from sending those values to your coroutine argument? Is storing them or sending an issue?

Comment: the speed values are fixed to default, sprinting or crouching. I need some way of getting the speed from the character controller and putting them into the WaitForSeconds

Comment: I meant the speed values you read in update, not the ones you declared. I'll try with an example. Let's say, you declare float currentSpeed variable, and in an update method, you assign values read from axes: currentSpeed = sqrt (x*x + z*z) * speed and then assign currentSpeed to your coroutine WaitForSecodns argument. Is that what you wanted? (I used this sqrt expression to count total speed)

Comment: Also note, that if you just add x and z values to the Vector, you will move faster when executing diagonal movement.

Comment: One more note, probably you would need to multiply that value by something, so you get the right time for your sound.

Comment: What I have done is currentSpeed = Mathf.Sqrt(x + z) * 0.4f; which is kind of getting to where I need and I think I can work with that and fix the issues. One problem I am having is making them work in the negative values. (btw I am a student and I am only on my second year on the course)

Comment: Use absolute value (Mathf.Abs I think) for x and z in your current speed expression. You need negative values for determining direction, but not for the timer - it doesn't matter if your x is -0.7 or 0.7, the speed of playing your sound will be the same.

Comment: it is almost working as expected I am now using currentSpeed = Mathf.Abs(x + z) / 0.4f; the only problem is reversing the amount. What I mean by this is when the player should be going at its slowest the sound speed is at its fastest. I need a way of starting at 0.4 and moving down to 0 the further the joystick is going

Comment: I am attempting to use mathf.clamp

Comment: Use Mathf.Abs(x) + Mathf.Abs(z), otherwise it won't work as expected. Consider x = -0.9 and z = 0.9

Comment: But how do I reverse the numbers so at the slowest x = 0.4 and at the highest x = 0.1 (as an example)

Comment: never mind, I had fixed this by adding Mathf.InverseLerp as a new float

Answer (score 0):

There is a package known as "SimpleInput" which has fully customizable joysticks that give you the x and y as separate values.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/simple-input-system-113033

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).